# Magento 2 searches by words inside the text

Tags: magento2, search

How to customize the search so that it searches by words inside the text

I tried `<queryReference clause="must" ref="search" />`, but it didn't help.

We have part numbers in our catalog and the Magento 2 search would only search if you type a query that PN starts with. For example, I have `WD5000AAKS` part number, if I search for `WD5000` it would give me the right results

Comment: Did you use the default Magento search?

Comment: Yes. This did not work for our needs.

Comment: I think this link use for https://ecommerce.hbwsl.com/blog/search-in-magento-2/

Comment: @denis Magento 2 doesn't provide words search. so you have to with any readymade extension.